# How to get Window Switcher functionality in Windows 10

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10, taskbar, shortcuts, autohotkey

In Windows 8 and previous, there was a shortcut in the C:\Users\Default\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch directory called "Switch Between Windows".  Executing this shortcut brought up the Window Switcher which you could navigate by rolling the mouse wheel and clicking to select a window to switch to.

After upgrading to Windows 10, this shortcut no longer works.  When executed, nothing happens.

I had previously set this up to allow switching between windows by clicking the mouse wheel to execute this shortcut, then rolling the wheel to select a window, then clicking again to select that window.  It's extremely fast and intuitive.  After the Windows 10 upgrade, this doesn't work anymore.

I'm using Autohotkey to do this scripting as well as provide some other shortcuts that I use daily.

Does anyone know how to programmatically trigger the Window Switcher in Windows 10, similar to the way it worked in 8/7/previous?

Note that the shortcut is apparently calling a shell function ([This](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/10135-window-switcher-shortcut-create-windows-8-a.html) pertains to creating the shortcut in Win 8).  Apparently the function may use a different GUID in Windows 10, but I have no idea how to find it.

I would also like to know how to open the new Task View window by executing some sort of function (vs clicking the icon or pressing the keyboard shortcut) as it may be a better choice to associate with the mouse wheel in Win 10.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MButton:: Send, #{Tab}


#IfWinActive ahk_class MultitaskingViewFrame  ; Task View window

    WheelUp:: Send, {Right}

    WheelDown:: Send, {Left}

    MButton:: Send, {Enter}

#IfWinActive
```